# Reset Circular Layout in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I've used a library downloaded from this link to create a `Circular Menu` using `Circular Layout` in an application.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1454 

The `menu` contains 6 items. I create the menu in `onCreate` and I want to create that menu again in `onResume` as I want to update some of the `menu items`. 

I want to create a `Circular Menu` with 6 items. As I have called the `menu` create `function` in both, number of `menu items` have got doubled, which is 12.
 
Below is a code excerpt which uses `Circular Menu`.

```
String[] mItemTexts = new String[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6" };
int[] mItemImgs = new int[] { R.drawable.im1,
                        R.drawable.im2, R.drawable.im3, R.drawable.im4, R.drawable.im5, R.drawable.im1};

mCircleMenuLayout = (CircleMenuLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_menulayout);
mCircleMenuLayout.setMenuItemIconsAndTexts(mItemImgs, mItemTexts);
```

What can I do to avoid getting the `Circular Menu` doubled?
Any suggestions or workarounds are much appreciated.
Thank you.

**PS**:
**EDIT**
I am using creation of the `Circular Menu` in `onResume` in the `Activity`. I don't finish the Activity with Circular Menu when starting another Activity, thus when I return from the newly started Activity again I find the Circular Menu has got doubled. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call your method only in `OnResume` and remove form `onCreate`

as `onResume` is called after the `onCreate`
  see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Comment: If it is doubling the data when calling it in onCreate() and onResume(). Then it will double the data when onResume() will get called twice.

Comment: Actually I did it. That's how I am using in the application. I don't finish the Activity with Circular Menu when starting another Activity, thus when I return from the newly started Activity again I find the Circular Menu has got doubled. That's the issue.

Comment: then remove it from the onResume because on resume is call again and again when you go and forth in activity stack

Comment: Say, I have created a Thread to listen incoming messages from a server in the Activity which the Circular Menu is created. Therefore I can't finish this Activity. Then I go to another Activity and I receive a new message and I return to the Activity with the Circular Menu. I want to update an image of the Circular Menu so that I can see I have got new messages from the server.
For this I have to create the menu in onResume, don't I?

Comment: you can update image or text by using reference also no need to recreate again and again